# MySQL - How to SUM times?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains date-time values in this format:

**START**

1/13/2009   7:00:00AM

**END**

1/13/2008   2:57:00PM

I use the 'str to date' function to convert these into a date-time format.

How do I calculate a difference between them?
And then sum it all up so that it displays in total hours (ie total hours for week is 40:53).

I was trying the timediff function but the results don't sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try looking into [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and [`SEC_TO_TIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time).

You would sum up the differences between the timestamps, then use that value (would be in milliseconds) to get the time:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(time_milis / 1000)
FROM (
   SELECT SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2)) as time_milis
   FROM table
)
```

Comment: Thank - I converted the date-time strings to seconds - calculated the difference - and then converted the seconds back to hours-minutes.

Comment: Correction - the time_to_sec function doesn't apply to the date portion - only the time portion - so taking 2009-08-25 01:06:00 minus 2009-08-24 15:35:00 results in a negative number.
I will need to use the timediff function.

Answer (score 48):

I think you have to use this code... it works :)

```
SELECT  
  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) ) AS total_time  
FROM time_table;
```

Comment: When I did this in MySQL I had to create a tmp table (with subquery), because the LIMIT wouldn't work otherwise: `select sec_to_time(sum(secs)) from (select TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time, start_time)) secs from reservations order by id desc limit 10) t;` Weird.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [MySQL DateDiff Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(endtime, starttime)) 
FROM somerecordstable
WHERE starttime > '[some date]' AND endtime <= '[some date]'
```

You could also try:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMEDIFF(endtime, starttime)) 
FROM somerecordstable
WHERE starttime > '[some date]' AND endtime <= '[some date]'
```

I haven't tested the second one, but I know the first one should work.

Comment: This is the right idea, but would give you an answer in days.  You'd need to do some multiplication or use another date function to convert that to hours:minutes

Comment: Thanks - it definitely needs to be hours as the query needs find total working time for employees for a given week.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT some_grouping_column, SUM(TIMEDIFF(datecol1,datecol2)) as tot_time
FROM my_table
GROUP BY some_grouping_column;
```

Comment: Is the result returned in minutes?

Comment: it returns hh:mm:ss 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 1):

Use [`TIMEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff).

```
SUM(TIMEDIFF(end, start))
```