# Converting Integer into time value, using SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-5.3

So I am using the following SQL search to add all time values in a database in the hours field of the logbook database:

```
SELECT SUM(hours) FROM logbook
```

But there is a problem as I recieve the output:

```
SUM(hours)
48514
```

Which is almost there!

What I really need it to do is this:

```
04:85:14
```

Which is in HH:MM:SS

and then from there, recognise that the MM is > 59 and therefore round the HH up by one, and in saying this prepare to do this to all of the 3 sections: HH MM SS.

But I have no idea how to do this!

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times

Comment: Umm, what unit is the hours column in? From what you've said, it seems like its a decimal number like "12345" meaning 1 hour, 23 minutes and 45 seconds. If that is the case, then you have a problem, since 60 === 100, and 70 > 100.

Comment: I think I missed something. does the column named "hours" holds values in hours or in seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this inside the query, but if you for some reason have to use php you could try this:

```
$hours = 48514;
function detailedHours($hours) {
    $hour = substr($hours,0,1);
    $minutes = substr($hours,1,2);
    $seconds = substr($hours,3,2);
    while($seconds>59) {
        $minutes++;
        $seconds-=60;
    }
    while($minutes>59) {
        $hour++;
        $minutes-=60;
    }
    return "$hour:$minutes:$seconds";
}
echo detailedHours($hours);
```