# SQL : Make a sum query

Tags: mysql, sql

With that request :

```
SELECT c.date, c.temps
FROM portail_cra c
WHERE c.date >=  '2013-06-01'
AND c.date <=  '2013-06-30'
AND c.id_user =  '147'
```

I have the following result :

[image]

I would like to make a sum of all the fields "temps" which avec the same date

For example :

```
date         temps
2013-06-03   08:30:00
2013-06-04   03:00:00
etc...
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT c.date, sum(c.temps)
FROM portail_cra c
WHERE c.date >=  '2013-06-01'
AND c.date <=  '2013-06-30'
AND c.id_user =  '147'
GROUP BY c.date
```