# MySql Troubles with date/time values

Tags: mysql, date

My table has a "TIME" type column. It has 2 rows with the following values for company a:
04:30:00
04:30:00
I wanted a total of those 2 rows to be written in a csv file using the code

```
enter code here

$sql2 = "SELECT company, SUM(intervalTime) 
   INTO OUTFILE 'd:/myfile/xxx.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   FROM june2013 GROUP BY company";  

     if (mysqli_query($con,$sql2))
    {
    echo "Summary added to text file successfully";
    }
    else
   {
     echo "Error transferring summary " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
```

The results were transferred to a csv file with the following values:
company a   86000
company b   420000
company c   292000

Total of 04:30:00 + 04:30:00 should be 9 hours. I got a total of 4300 + 4300.
Any idea how I solve this problem?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times

Answer (score 1):

You can't just SUM a time column like that, you need to convert it into a numeric value first (maths works with numbers).

Try this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT company, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( intervalTime ) ) ) 
   INTO OUTFILE 'd:/myfile/xxx.csv'
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   FROM june2013 GROUP BY company";
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that for each company there are two rows. Then, this query might help:

```
select
    t1.company AS com,
    addtime(
        (select intervalTime from june2013 AS t2 where t2.company = t1.company LIMIT 1),
    (select intervalTime from june2013 AS t2 where t2.company = t1.company LIMIT 1, 1)
) AS dif
into outfile 'd:/myfile/xxx.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
from june2013 as t1
group by t1.company;
```

The dates are summed correctly using function addtime(time1, time2). See mysql documentation.