# How to sum time using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to sum the time in a table. In my table there is duration field and the type is "time" .

I have tried this query it returns only seconds. but I need hours and minutes and seconds.

in my table there is two rows one row has 00:20:10 and another is 00:15:05

so I need to display as 00:35:15

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( MINUTE( duration ) ) ) AS totaltime
FROM users
```

Comment: please check it sir my answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - How to SUM times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times)

Comment: please explain what that query is outputting for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this one:

```
  SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `duration` ) ) ) AS totaltime
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to seconds and then back to time

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( duration ) ) ) AS totaltime
```