# Using SUM SEC_TO_TIME in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

Reference from [How to sum time using mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733184/how-to-sum-time-using-mysql)

I want to `SUM` Field `LogsFormatted.Late` Every month with query :

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE 
          WHEN MONTH (LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 1 
          THEN SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(LogsFormatted.Late)))
          ELSE 0 END 
        ) AS '1'
FROM
    HrAttLogsFormatted AS LogsFormatted
```

But the result is

> 1111 - Invalid use of group function

Where is the problem with the query? resulting in an error output.. Thank you in advance

**[EDIT-SOLVED]** *It's Solved with simply apply*

Change format `SUM` at the beginning of the query

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(                                                    
  CASE WHEN MONTH(LogsFormatted.DateIn) = 1 THEN 
    TIME_TO_SEC(LogsFormatted.Late) END)                       
) AS '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the `sum()` so many times.  You can also move the `case` condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(lf.Late)) 
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted lf
WHERE MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1 ;
```

If you want conditional aggregation, then do:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(lf.Late) END)
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted lf;
```

Comment: Thank you in advance, It's work but the result displays seconds, what I want to make is the format of minutes and seconds, is there another way? Result `16208936` i need to convert this to `10:53:16`

Comment: Just try simply apply the `sec_to_time` like `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(lf.DateIn) = 1 THEN TIME_TO_SEC(lf.Late) END))
FROM HrAttLogsFormatted lf;`

Comment: @tim Thank you in advance, It's work just simply apply