# How to use a variable outside of the loop it came from? PHP

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, foreach

**I have updated my code since I posted.**

I am attempting to echo a variable outside of a loop it was calculated in.

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row){ //loop to display all team members


   echo '<table border="1"><tr><td>User</td><td>Hours</td></tr>';

   $this->db->select('users.USER_EMAIL'); //we want to display the users' emails who are in this team.
   $this->db->from('users');
   $this->db->join('user_teams', 'users.USER_ID = user_teams.USER_ID'); //we need to join these tabels in order to get this
   $this->db->join('teams', 'teams.TEAM_ID = user_teams.TEAM_ID');
   $this->db->where('teams.TEAM_NAME', $row->TEAM_NAME); //search for the team name that we are currently looking at
   $team_query = $this->db->get();


   echo '<h2>Team: ';
   echo $row->TEAM_NAME;
   echo '</h2>';
$total = date('h:i:s', NULL);
var_dump($total); //outputs "01:00:00" as a string
foreach ($team_query->result() as $team_row) {

var_dump($total); //outputs "01:00:00" as a string


echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $team_row->USER_EMAIL;
echo '</td>';

$this->db->select('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORK_HOURS` ) ) ) AS totalHours');
$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $team_row->USER_EMAIL);
$hours= $this->db->get('user_hours')->row()->totalHours;

echo '<td>';
echo $hours; //outputs "00:11:01" as a string, that is the correct value 
echo '</td>';
var_dump($hours); //outputs "00:11:01" as a string. still correct
$total += $hours; //im guessing the += operators do not work on time
var_dump($total); //outputs 1 as int, not correct. should be "00:11:01" as a string for the first time around the loop

echo '</tr>';
echo '<br />';
}
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo 'Total'; //outputs 1 as int
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $total; //outputs 1 as int
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
     echo '</table>';

}
```

**Could it have something to do with it being in the time format?**

What is the correct way to add time, if there is one?

I am using codeigniter 3x if that matters at all.

Let me know if any additional info is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apparently, your `$team_query->result()` returns nothing, and your script doesn't even enter the `foreach`. Try to debug this one first. (And yes, you should always initialize your variables beforehand.)

Comment: The variable $hours does output correctly. So the query is returning results

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's a bad idea to run SQL queries during the loop. Consider making this calculation a part of your $team_query instead.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I'll keep that in mind

Comment: Might be a silly question, but: are you sure you're outputting $total AFTER the `foreach`? If yes: are you sure that nothing happens after the `foreach` and before you output $total? "Outside the loop" sounds a bit vague. Would be nice to see the full code between the loop and the $total output.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I added more of the code.

Comment: @SergeyVidusov $hours is the sum of a bunch of different time data that is in my database. that is why I think that when I use $total += $hours+$total, it is not adding correctly. I'm not sure how to add two pieces of data in time format

Comment: Thank you. Looks legit to me. I'd try to `var_dump($hours)` inside the loop and see if something nasty gets into it. (I wonder why you put your H1 headers between the table rows, but I guess it's a whole other issue.)

Comment: @SergeyVidusov I gave the var_dump a try and nothing nasty is getting into it. It just is not adding the values it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

May be your query result returns ZERO number of rows. Make sure $team_query have results.

result() as $team_row)
 {

$total += $hours;

  } ?>

Comment: It does return rows. The variable $hours outputs correctly

Comment: First you have to create initial value for $total. So out side the loop you should declare the $total=0; that is begining of the loop.

Comment: I have added more of the code. I am positive the query returns results. Could it have something to do with it being a time format?

Comment: try this $this->db->select('SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `USER_WORK_HOURS` )/3600 ) ) AS totalHours');
$this->db->where('USER_EMAIL', $team_row->USER_EMAIL);
$hours= $this->db->get('user_hours')->row()->totalHours;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
       $hours= $this->db->get('user_hours')->row()->totalHours;

        make sure that $hours variable contains an integer value 
        or float value 
        it should not a be string and also not be empty.


You can initialize  $total = 0;  $hours=0;
```

Comment: the values I am grabbing from my database are in a time format. That is probably why they are not adding correctly. Is there a way to add them without any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetical addition (`+` operator) won't work on strings like "01:00:00". You must either convert them to seconds prior to adding (via `TIME_TO_SEC()` MySQL function), or calculate the whole value via SQL, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times).

Also, it would be interesting to look at the SQL prior to the loop (the one you retrieve via $query): I'm pretty sure you can get all the data you need there in one go, without nested queries and PHP calculations.