# Summing duration values (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

All, 
I have a MySQL table named duration which contains names and total duration time for separate locations visited over one day. I need to total the times and show them for each person (in hours, mins, seconds format). I believe I need to convert to seconds first and then sum and convert back to hh:mm:ss) but am struggling with the correct SQL code (prefer not to use a stored procedure). Any assistance appreciated.

```
Name    Duration

Fred    00:00:20
John    12:39:10
Jack    03:59:20
Stacy   19:17:34
Stacy   03:39:00
John    04:20:30
Jack    00:29:17
John    03:23:50
Fred    12:17:29
```

i.e. Jack's total duration 04:28:37, Stacy's total duration 22:56:34

Comment: This question seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times

Comment: What is the datatype of the duration column?

Comment: Datatype is TIME

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( time_to_sec( duration ) ) ) 
from yourtable 
group by name;
```

> **For example - to get sum:**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))) from ( select '01:00:00' as duration union all select '00:35:03' as duration ) as test;
+-------------------------------------------+
| SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))) |
+-------------------------------------------+
| 01:35:03.000000                           |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))),'%H:%i:%S') from ( select '01:00:00' as duration union all select '00:35:03' as duration ) as test;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))),'%H:%i:%S') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 01:35:03                                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

> **to test group sum**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select name,TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))),'%H:%i:%S') from ( select 'a' as name, '01:00:00' as duration union all select 'a' as name, '00:35:03' as duration union all select 'b' as name, '05:26:00' as duration ) as test group  by name;
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name | TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(sum(time_to_sec( duration ))),'%H:%i:%S') |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| a    | 01:35:03                                                          |
| b    | 05:26:00                                                          |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Just add a group by name (+1)

Comment: close but this is showing the total time and not for each name and also displays the sql code in the result

Comment: @Active: I edited and added group by duration, hope now its clear

Comment: Thanks Akshay Hegde, much appreciated

Comment: Spoke too soon, there is a sql exception if the hours column is more than 24 hours (600 hours in one cell), is there a resolution for this?