# mysql/mariadb date column time add to get total time

Tags: php, mariadb

I am working on a check in out front desk register and hit a wall when attempting to add the total times for all visits by individuals or companies: when i run the following query:

```
$yearStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-01-01')));
        $today = date("Y-m-d",time());
        $sql = "SELECT visCompany, count(visCompany) as accumilatedVisits, sum(timeVisited) as total_time from cards where cards.dateOfVisit BETWEEN '$yearStart' AND '$today' GROUP BY cards.visCompany ORDER BY accumilatedVisits DESC";
```

I get the sum of the two numbers but not in the correct format, but I cannot figure or find a better way to do it... I had at the start the following times saved in my Cards table: `00:29:18` and `00:05:43` which when added together give me 3461 which would be correct-ish if you put a space between 34 and 61, the total should be `00:35:01` and the values seem to be there but i would think that there is a cleaner way of accomplishing the correctly added and formatted values... I have been scowering the mariadb kb and even trying to find the solution here... I would be okay figuring out a way to do the formatting and the minute correction in php too.. but would prefer to use sql to get the desired result.

Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: I know I posted as such not 15 minutes ago

Comment: No worries, it's just better to close duplicates as these are the SO guidelines

Comment: is there a way I can flag my own when such things happen in the future?

Comment: Have a look over the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) list

Answer (score 0):

Whops i put a duplicate... found the answer:: [MySQL - How to SUM times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329458/mysql-how-to-sum-times)

my new query:: `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(cards.timeVisited))) as total_time_visited FROM cards;`

tested and worked with the result being `00:35:01`.

Sorry about the duplicate... And thanks for reading.